# How to handle multiple values which have multiple subsets?

Tags: data-science-model, feature-engineering

I am new to datascience. I am trying to predict tab position in msword using features like paragraph text, font name, tab count, tab index etc. In tab position there may be 0 values  or multiple values like ([0.5,4,0.5],[1.5,1,2],[6.8,2,11]).

Here, Mid value i.e. 4,1 and 2 are the types of tabs in msword where 4 represents indent 0.5,4,0.5 here left 0.5 represents first line indent and right 0.5 represent hanging indent. Similarly, in  [6.8,2,11] 2 represents right tab and left value indicate that the tab starts from 6.8 and stops or tab stop is in the 11 cm. How can handle such values? Using one hot encoding does not seem fit for this problem because tab position are continuous (linear) values.